# How to use multiprocessing on a map that takes in pandas dataframe and create new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a dataset of around 2 million Tweets that I would like to perform sentiment analysis on using Asari and a few others.
Currently, I am using apply to get the sentiments and creating new columns for them.
To try to speed up the process, I'd like to use multiprocessing but am not sure how to go about it.

Without the multiprocessor, my code looks like the below: (producing new columns)

```
def asa(x):
    asari_1=sonar.ping(x)
    hug_1=nlp(x)
    return asari_1['top_class'], asari_1['classes'][0]['confidence'], asari_1['classes'][1]['confidence'], hug_1[0]["label"], hug_1[0]["score"]
df_split[i][['asar','asar neg','asar pos','hugposneg','hugscore']]=df_split[i].apply(lambda row: asa(row.Tweet),axis='columns',result_type='expand')
#df_split[0]['asar'],df_split[0]['asar neg'],df_split[0]['asar pos'],df_split[0]['hugposneg'],df_split[0]['hug score']=zip(*df_split[0]['Tweet'].map(asa))   map version
```

For the multiprocessor I tried the below, but as you can probably guess, they came back with errors such as 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'p'

```
%%time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        j[['asar','asar neg','asar pos','hugposneg','hugscore']]=j.p.apply(lambda row: asa(row.Tweet),axis='columns',result_type='expand')
#        j['asar'],j['asar neg'],j['asar pos'],j['hugposneg'],j['hug score']=p.zip(*j['Tweet'].map(asa))

j
```

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`swifter`](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter) package:

```
pip install swifter
```

(Note that you may want to use this in a virtualenv to avoid version conflicts with installed dependencies.)

Swifter works as a plugin for pandas, allowing you to reuse the `apply` function:

```
import swifter

def some_function(data):
    return data * 10

data['out'] = data['in'].swifter.apply(some_function)
```

It will automatically figure out the most efficient way to parallelize the function, no matter if it's vectorized (as in the above example) or not.

[More examples](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter/blob/master/examples/swifter_apply_examples.ipynb) are available on GitHub. Note that the package is under active development, so the API may change.

Also note that this [will not work automatically](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter/blob/master/docs/documentation.md#8-pandasdataframeswifterallow_dask_on_stringsenabletrueapply) for string columns. When using strings, Swifter will fallback to a “simple” Pandas `apply`, which will not be parallel. In this case, even forcing it to use `dask` will not create performance improvements, and you would be better off just splitting your dataset manually and [parallelizing using `multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).